# SwiftUI center items in LazyVGrid

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and am trying to center elements inside the `LazyVGrid` View.

Here is what I have currently:

[image]

Using:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(red: 75/255, green: 0, blue: 130/255).ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 30))], alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                let letters = wordToArray(word: testWord)
                ForEach(Array(letters.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { letter in
                    Text(String(letter.element).capitalized)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(width:30, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see, this only aligns the elements to the left - I also do not know the number of characters that I may need to display. I would also like the keep the spacing between them the same as above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: VStack(alignment: .center) doesn't help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 options

```
struct CenteredLVSView: View {
    @State var letters: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E","A", "B", "C", "D", "E","A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    //Specify column count and it will justify/center by width
    @State var columnCount: Int = 5
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(red: 75/255, green: 0, blue: 130/255).ignoresSafeArea()
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 30
                 //If you set max it will center on width if smaller than max, uncomment below
                 //, maximum: 40
            )), count: columnCount), spacing: 10){
                ForEach(Array(letters.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { letter in
                    Text(String(letter.element).capitalized)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(width:30, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: LazyVGrid - Justified]

Change to `LazyHGrid`

```
struct CenteredLVSView: View {
    @State var letters: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E","A", "B", "C", "D", "E","A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    //Specify row count and it will justify/center height
    @State var rowCount: Int = 5
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(red: 75/255, green: 0, blue: 130/255).ignoresSafeArea()
            LazyHGrid(rows: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 30
                //If you set max it will center if smaller than max, height uncomment below
                //, maximum: 40
            )), count: rowCount), spacing: 10){
                ForEach(Array(letters.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { letter in
                    Text(String(letter.element).capitalized)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .frame(width:30, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: LazyHGrid - Justified]

And as mentioned in the comments if you set a `maximum` they will be centered/justified to that max

LazyHGrid w/ 3 rows with a maximum of 40
[image: LazyHGrid w/ 3 rows]

LazyVGrid w/ 5 columns with a maximum of 40
[image: LazyVGrid w/ 5 columns]

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and couldn't solve it so I used a ScrollView and foreach to achieve the same way I need it

```
struct Subview: View {
var Items = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
var body: some View {
    ZStack(){
        Color("AccentColor").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack{
            HStack(alignment:.center){
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false){
                HStack(alignment:.center){
                ForEach(Items, id: \.self) { item in
                Button {
                    } label: {
                Text("\(item)")
                }.frame(width:50,height: 50, alignment: .center).background(Color.red).cornerRadius(25)
                                
                }
                            
                            
                }.frame(width:geo.size.width,height: geo.size.height ,alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        }
        
    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, alignment: .center)
            
}    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those who are still looking for answer like me, I have achieved solution in adaptive grid like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let adaptiveColumn = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 250, maximum: 350))
    ]
    var body: some View {
        
        LazyVGrid(columns: adaptiveColumn, spacing: 20) {
            
            ForEach(1..<5) { item in
                Text(String(item))
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                    .padding(20)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image]
The catch is you have to set minimum width so that another item does not able to fit in the right. If there is enough space for another item in the right, `LazyVGrid` will reserve that space for new item.